# How to execute python BDD scripts using behavex

Tags: python, python-behave

I have developed BDD scripts with the help of behave using python. I am able to develop and run scripts using behave. Now I want to use behavex for parallel execution. For that, I have reviewed the documentation which I added below and when I try to run it as mentioned in the documentation I get the following problem.

**behavex documentation link:** https://behavex.readthedocs.io/

**feature file location:** <project_name>/features/myfile.feature

**The script inside feature file:**

```
Feature: Testing scenarios 

     @TAG_1
     Scenario: Scenario1
         ---------
         ---------

     @TAG_2
     Scenario: Scenario2
         ---------
         ---------
```

**Terminal CMD(Trigger the run):**
behavex -t @TAG_1 ~@TAG_2

**The error displayed on the terminal after running the above command:**
Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '<file_name>'

I am new to behavex if any of you know how to run multiple scenarios using bahavex please let me know

Comment: You should remove the tag `robotframework` because your question is not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the tests from the root folder of your project, so BehaveX will look for the "features" folder from the execution path. It is expected that the steps modules are located into the "<project>/features/steps" folder.

Inside the "steps" folder, you can have the folders structure you consider, as BehaveX will iterate the full structure looking for the steps implementation.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue is in the tags.
Your command is: `behavex -t @TAG_1 ~@TAG_2`

If you need to run the tests that have TAG_1 and not TAG_2, you should run:
`behavex -t @TAG_1 -t ~@TAG_2`